# Javascript random number with weighted probability

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, random

I'm trying to create a function with the following signature:

```
function weightedRandom (target, probability) {
  // calculate weighted random number that is more likely to be near target value
  return value; // number from 0 to 1
}
```

It should do the following:

- Generate random number from 0 to 1, but not including 1
- The probability of any given number being picked in that range is NOT evenly distributed
- There is a greater chance that the number picked is near the **target** value (target is also a value from 0 to 1)
- The probability curve would look like a bell curve, where the target value has the highest probability and the values around it taper down, but all values in the 0 to 1 range would still have a chance of getting picked.
- The weight of this chance can be adjusted with the **probability** value, where a value of 0 means there is no weighting applied to the randomness and 1 means that almost all numbers picked will be clustered right around the target value.

For example, `weightedRandom(0.8, 0.2)` would result in a random value that is 20% likely to be clustered around the value 0.8, but could be any number from 0 up to 1. If the probability was 0.5, then even more of the resulting random values returned would be near 0.8. I think maybe there needs to be another parameter to define the width of the cluster (standard deviation?).

I am not a mathematician, but I have been told to look at [Beta Distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) as a possible tool to help:

[image]

I've found some NPM modules that have `beta` functions, but I'm not sure how to use them to solve this problem:

- https://github.com/AndreasMadsen/mathfn
- https://github.com/jstat/jstat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: randomly choose between two easier distributions, also Inverse transform sampling

## Combine two distributions

If you had a flat distribution, you could choose any value in your range equally. If you had a Gaussian distribution, you could choose a value near your Gaussian's mean. So consider randomly choosing to do one or other of these.

If you want the random value to be near the target `t` 80% of the time, and elsewhere the other 20%. Suppose that 'near' means within 2 standard deviations, and we'll take the variance to be `v`. So the range `(t-2*v)` to `(t+2*v)` needs to cover P(0.8).

Suppose we will randomly use either a flat distribution or a Gaussian distribution; the probability of a random value falling in a given range is then the sum of the two distributions, weighted by the bias of the distribution choice. If we choose the Gaussian, we will end up with a value [within 2 std.dev. 95.45% of the time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule). If we take the Gaussian X% of the time, then the near probability Pn = P(t-2v to t+2v) = 0.9545*X + (1-X)(4v/r), where r is the full range, and (4v/r) is then the proportion of the flat distribution inside the range.

To get this Pn to 80%:

```
0.8 = 0.9545*X + (1-X)(4v/r).
```

We have 2 unknowns, so if we also require a very near probability that the value is within 1 std.dev of the target 60% of the time, then

```
0.6 = 0.6827*X + (1-X)(2v/r).
```

Rearranging for (2v/r):

```
(0.8 - 0.9545*X)/(1-X)*2 = (2v/r)
(0.6 - 0.6826*x)/(1-X) = (2v/r)
```

Equating and simplifying

```
X = 0.81546
```

Thus:

```
var range = [0, 10];
var target = 7.0;
var stddev = 1.0;
var takeGauss = (Math.random() < 0.81546);
if(takeGauss) {
  // perform gaussian sampling (normRand has mean 0), resample if outside range
  while(1) {
    var sample = ((normRand()*stddev) + target);
    if(sample >= range[0] && sample <= range[1]) {
      return sample;
    }
  }
} else {
  // perform flat sampling
  return range[0]+(Math.random()*(range[1]-range[0]));
}
```

I think this gives you the required shape, lets you choose two probabilities for near and very near probabilities, but avoids too much complexity.

As I'm being asked to provide more implementation, I've found [a normal variate generator (thanks Prof Ian Neath)](http://memory.psych.mun.ca/tech/snippets/random_normal/):

```
function normRand() {
    var x1, x2, rad;

    do {
        x1 = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
        x2 = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
        rad = x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
    } while(rad >= 1 || rad == 0);

    var c = Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(rad) / rad);

    return x1 * c;
};
```

## Inverse transform sampling

The first way I considered was to use [Inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), which I'll attempt to explain here.

Suppose we have a distribution where values from 0 to 4 are equally likely, but only half as likely as values from 4 to 10. The total probability is 4a + 6(2*a) = 1, so a=1/16:

[image: step probability function doubling at 4 from a sixteenth to an eighth]

Suppose you had a function which, when given a value between 0 and 1 in, produced a value between 0 and 10; it is still [monotonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) (no minima/maxima), but if you fed it every 0.01 increment from 0 to 1 you'd get a ratio of 4:6*2 = 1:3, so 3x as many values over 4 as under it. That function would look like this:

[image]

We have linear segment from z=0 to z=1/3, where x(1/3) = 4, and then a linear segment from z=1/3 to z=1 continuing on to x(1)=10. If we choose a random number z from the flat probability distribution between 0 and 1, then x(z) will be distributed with the first 1/3 of the range giving values up to 4, as required, and the remainder above.

z(x), then, is the inverse transform that takes a flat distribution and makes yields values from the desired distribution. If you want to plot it, it is `x<(1/3) ? 9*x : 12*x -1`.

The game is then to construct a distribution that you are happy with, and invert it to get the inverse transform, either by using pieces as above or by analytically inverting it, or some approximation (Gaussian inverse cannot be written down analytically). With this you can transform any flat-distributed sample into the desired distribution.

Sampling from the above step distribution would be done like this:

```
// transform 0-1 flat to 0-10 stepped
function stepInvTransform(z) {
    return (3*z < 1 ? 9*z : (12*z - 1));
}

// sample via inv transform
var sample = stepInvTransform(Math.random());
```

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one upvote for such an in-depth and mathematical answer! However, I'm not sure how to convert this into an implementation. If you could you provide some pseudo-code, it would help tremendously. I need some time to process this and try to figure out how to convert all the math into a javascript function that fits the required signature.

Comment: Interesting and educational though your answer is, I'd say it's more of a programmers/computer-science exchange style answer than a SO one. This site is for Q&A concerning _specific, code-related_ problems. Adding some theory to explain your answer is fine, but offering nothing but theory makes this answer incomplete

Comment: +1 good answer. It must be so frustrating for you to get remarks like "add code" - it's definitely not the main point here :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I take your point, though the question was definitely on the abstract end rather than implementation. Anyway, I've found a gaussian sample generator and filled in the blanks. BenjaminGruenbaum: I won't take it to heart :)

Comment: @PhilH: I know my comment may have been a tad pedantic, and yes, the question itself focussed more on the theory rather than actual code, so in fact the question wasn't the best fit for this site. Anyway, you might want to change the function you added to `setInvTransform(x)`, instead of `z`, given that the function body uses `x` throughout. +1 anyways

Comment: @PhilH: Thanks for adding an implementation. I thought it was clear in my question that I was looking for implementation help, but maybe it could have been more obvious.

Comment: @PhilH: I've used your code to implement this: http://jsfiddle.net/tauren/9EFkV/  It looks like this approach may work well, but I'm unclear how to adjust the clustering. Right now, the results are highly clustered around the target with only a few outliers. I'd like to be able to adjust the clustering with a parameter, so that the results can vary from no clustering at all all the way up to 99% of the results are clustered around the target. For instance, how would I get about 40% of the results within 1.0 of the target? Right now it is around 60-80%.

Comment: @PhilH: I've updated the jsfiddle to indicate percentage of results within 1 of the target, percentage within 2 of target, and percentage outside of that range (outliers): http://jsfiddle.net/tauren/9EFkV/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would make an expansion of the range (Math.round()*2) and then use some other function `f: [0,2] -> [0,1]` that is not 1-1 mapping back to the 0-1 interval but maps more values to the area of 0.8. E.g., `f(x) = c*x^2 - d*x^3` and tuning `c` and `d` such that the distribution suits you.

See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2ax%5E2+-+x%5E3). You can just play with the values or derive the function and see how `c` and `d` interact. Of course you can use other functions for more precision like polynomials with more degrees or mix polynomials with exponential functions to get all sorts of behavior, but this is a question of what you really want, and how you would like it to behave.

Comment: Good ideas, but I'm not sure how to apply them. The problem is that `0.8` is just an example, and this function needs to support any `target` from 0 to 1. I still need to find an automatable way to find an appropriate `c` and `d` value for any given `target`. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Well, I would take a piece of paper, derive the function, and then try to express with "0.8" and "0.2" the values of `c` and `d`. Then you can put this into code, namely, CalcCD(0.8,0.2) - which outputs `c` and `d`. From there on, you just apply the above. *Note, the math part may be a bit annoying, but worth the trouble if you don't find a package that dose the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well. the probability is a quite easy thing to do:

```
//get the probability factor:
var prob = +(probability.charAt(2));//0.[2] <-- coerces 2 to number
```

This is the max number of *tries* you're going to give the RNG. But then, to see how close you are getting to the target must be taken into account, which we might do with a while loop.

```
var targetDigit = (''+ target).charAt(2),
    prob = +((''+probability).charAt(2)),
    rn,
    closest = 0;//keep track of closest hit
if (probability == 0)
    return Math.random();
do
{
    rn = Math.random();
    //reduce chances for too great of distances, regenerate, but don't count!
    if (Math.abs(rn.toFixed(1).charAt(2)-targetDigit) >= target/2)
        rn = Math.random();
    if (rn.toFixed(1).charAt(2) === targetDigit)
        return rn;//on the money
    if (Math.abs(target - rn) < Math.abs(target - closest))
        closest = rn;
} while (prob--);//while probability left
return closest;//return the closest generated value
```

When I tried this code, with the parameters `.8` as target, and `.4` as probability, I got the following return values:

```
0.8257349738919855 // hit!
0.7696360136541552 // -0.1, close
0.7542727420001457 // -0.1, close
0.9837384401271013 // +0.1, close
0.3078854698178465 // -0.5, far
0.8178311114230021 // hit!
0.6079441227457084 // -0.2, fairly close
```

Which, I take it, is close to what you'd expect.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll give it a try and see if the results are close enough to meet my needs.